# having difficulty in understanding as where to keep the Routes in nested routes and passing all the props to that route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am having some difficulty in understanding as whee to keep the routes and how to do nested routing with reactjs .
Another problem is how to pass the props to that Component being rendered because of routes.
Here is the code.
This is the render part of the code.
Currently, I am on home/coupons 
and I want to add new routes say it should route to
coupons/5
or say coupons/xyz/5
or say coupons/xyz/pqr/6
or say coupons/xyz/pqr/abc/10

```
 render(){
    console.log("this.props",this.props);
    const {classes,Provider}=this.props;
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <FlexHeader
              center={
                <Fragment>
                    <h1>Coupons</h1>
                 </Fragment>
               }
              />
             {this.renderContent()}
             <Route path="/coupons/:id" component ={CouponsRedeem}/>
         </Fragment>);
 }
```

Another thing is how do I pass props while routing from one place to another .

```
onCardClick =()=>{
        console.log('card clicked');
        this.props.history.push({
              pathname: '/coupons/:5',
       })
    }
```

I want to pass down props as well from the current component to the newly rendered Component.
I am including more part of the code .

```
class Coupons extends React.Component{
    onCardClick =()=>{
        console.log('card clicked');
        this.props.history.push({
              pathname: '/coupons/5',
       })
    }
    render(){
       const {classes,Provider}=this.props;
        return(
              <Fragment>
              <FlexHeader
                 center={
                     <Fragment>
                       <h1>Coupons</h1>
                     </Fragment>
                 }
              />
              {this.renderContent()}
              <Route path="/coupons/:id" component ={CouponsRedeem}/>

              </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the routing part of App.js

```
<Fragment>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/cricket/:description/:id"
        component={CricketMatchCenterLoadable}
      />
     <Route
        path="/football/:description/:id"
        component={FootballMatchCenterLoadable}
      />
      <Route path="/news/:slug/:id" component={NewsDetailLoadable} />
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginLoadable} />
      <Route path="/home" component={HomeRootLoadable} />
      <Route path="/landing1" component={LandingRedLoadable} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={routeProps => (
          <Landing
            prefetchHomeRoute={HomeRootLoadable.preload}
            {...routeProps}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
    <BottomSnackbar />
  </Fragment>
```

As i click on it goes to another route home/cricket .Here is the homeroot.js

```
<Fragment>
        <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute
            path={match.url + "/me"}
            renderFunc={routeProps => <ProfileLoadable {...routeProps} />}
          />
          <ProtectedRoute
            path={match.url + "/coupons"}
            renderFunc={routeProps => <CouponsLoadable {...routeProps} />}
          />
          <Route path={match.url + "/news"} component={NewsFeedLoadable} />

          <Route path={match.url} component={MatchesListRoute} />


        </Switch>

        <BottomNavigation
          value={getIndexForRoute(pathname)}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          showLabels
          className={classes.root}
        >
          <BottomNavigationAction label="Matches" icon={<AllInclusiveIcon />} />
          <BottomNavigationAction label="Trending" icon={<WhatsHotIcon />} />
          {isAuthenticated && [
            <BottomNavigationAction
              key="couponsTab"
              label="Coupons"
              icon={<LocalOfferIcon />}
            />,
            <BottomNavigationAction
              key="meTab"
              label="Profile"
              icon={<PersonIcon />}
            />
          ]}
        </BottomNavigation>
      </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `:` while passing the path to history.push

```
onCardClick =()=>{
    console.log('card clicked');
    this.props.history.push({
          pathname: '/coupons/5',
   })
}
```

Comment: Hey shubham ,I did that and I removed that : but I don't see my component being rendered .

Comment: You can look into the more added details now .

Comment: how does your Route config look like

Comment: There is no one route config file.instead it is this way .I will show the code .